# Node.js application on Heroku: failed with exit status 8 - application-name package?

Tags: node.js, heroku

```
2014-08-18T06:12:54.374054+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node app.js
2014-08-18T06:12:54.374153+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-08-18T06:12:53.681620+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T06:12:53.681638+00:00 app[web.1]: > application-name@0.0.1 start /app
2014-08-18T06:12:53.681641+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2014-08-18T06:12:53.681642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T09:08:41.257725+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-08-18T09:08:41.258006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
2014-08-18T09:08:41.257553+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
2014-08-18T09:08:41.200012+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T09:08:41.256092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
2014-08-18T09:08:41.328006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-08-18T09:08:41.257897+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-08-18T09:08:41.255669+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
2014-08-18T09:08:41.256012+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-18T09:08:41.255860+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-08-18T09:08:41.260452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-08-18T09:08:41.257637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-08-18T09:08:41.305747+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-08-18T09:08:41.257819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node app.js
2014-08-18T1
5:48:38.818790+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818796+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818798+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:37:17)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818802+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818803+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818809+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:906:3
2014-08-18T15:48:38.852005+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T15:48:38.963950+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-08-18T15:48:38.964092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-18T15:48:38.964243+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
2014-08-18T15:48:38.964845+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
2014-08-18T15:48:38.964941+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-08-18T15:48:38.965068+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-08-18T15:48:38.972537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node app.js
2014-08-18T15:48:38.972644+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-08-18T15:48:38.972791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
2014-08-18T15:48:38.972864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-08-18T15:48:39.003054+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2014-08-18T15:48:39.003239+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-08-18T15:48:39.003377+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-08-18T15:48:39.034280+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
2014-08-18T15:48:39.034505+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
2014-08-18T15:48:39.034627+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2014-08-18T15:48:39.053234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-18T15:48:39.053356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-08-18T15:48:39.053445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-08-18T15:48:39.053666+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2014-08-18T15:48:34.297578+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T15:48:34.297596+00:00 app[web.1]: > application-name@0.0.1 start /app
2014-08-18T15:48:34.297598+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2014-08-18T15:48:34.297599+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T15:48:38.807843+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-18T15:48:38.963600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
2014-08-19T01:18:03.335113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=www.supercuber.com request_id=2a27f766-9eba-4b64-a2eb-be9d666cbc6f fwd="208.115.111.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-19T06:27:09.423387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=supercuber.com request_id=cc9ecb87-a01f-4d75-97c9-83327bc0ea12 fwd="188.40.249.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-19T07:29:59.457621+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-19T07:30:05.636929+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T07:30:05.636950+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T07:30:05.636947+00:00 app[web.1]: > application-name@0.0.1 start /app
2014-08-19T07:30:06.272653+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
2014-08-19T07:30:06.274102+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
2014-08-19T07:30:06.272136+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
2014-08-19T07:30:06.274218+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
2014-08-19T07:30:06.251287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273691+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2014-08-19T07:30:06.275894+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2014-08-19T07:30:06.276020+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2014-08-19T07:30:06.272036+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273990+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2014-08-19T07:30:05.636949+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273008+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273285+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
2014-08-19T07:30:06.276125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273186+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2014-08-19T07:30:06.274337+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2014-08-19T07:30:06.271697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
2014-08-19T07:30:06.272746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273099+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node app.js
2014-08-19T07:30:06.271900+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-08-19T07:30:06.273861+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2014-08-19T07:30:07.487403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-19T13:13:46.311103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-08-19T13:13:43.465194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-08-20T01:13:05.625215+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/BingSiteAuth.xml" host=www.supercuber.com request_id=60a05958-5b68-45b3-896d-4ffda351783e fwd="131.253.38.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-20T01:13:05.480594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.supercuber.com request_id=4ff53541-8a8d-43b6-a39c-db40924c9eac fwd="131.253.38.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-08-20T02:43:17.133291+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2014-08-20T02:43:17.133270+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T02:43:17.133292+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T02:43:17.133289+00:00 app[web.1]: > application-name@0.0.1 start /app
2014-08-20T02:43:17.732000+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2014-08-20T02:43:17.732121+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
2014-08-20T02:43:17.710159+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T02:43:17.731539+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
2014-08-20T02:43:17.731795+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 8
2014-08-20T02:43:17.733311+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
2014-08-20T03:10:55.501614+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.supercuber.com request_id=7ed9a3bd-755c-4d7b-bc23-1a3fa2152919 fwd="98.182.28.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This is what gets output in my application logs that the error code tells me to check. My research online and here on stack overflow has shown that this error seems to appear for a large variety of use cases, and Im not sure why its appearing now? My application runs fine locally. In fact it used to run on heroku, except when I just made new changes and tried to push them to heroku this happens when I try and start the app.

Edit: here is whats in my app.js currently:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Answer (score 1):

npm is telling you what's wrong:

```
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818790+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818796+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818798+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:37:17)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818802+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818803+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
2014-08-18T15:48:38.818809+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:906:3
```

If you're using express 4.x.x, you must `require` the middleware separately.

For example, if you are using `express.bodyParser()`, you will need to replace it by performing the following steps:

1. Run `npm install body-parser --save`
2. Add this require near the top of your page with your `require` statements: `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
3. Find in your app:

   - `app.use(express.bodyParser());`
   - `app.use(express.urlencoded());`
   - `app.use(express.json());`
4. Replace ALL with this ONE line: `app.use(bodyParser());`

You must then complete these steps for all the other middleware your application uses and is listed on connect's [migration guide](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware).

Comment: how do I know what the middleware is? For example I don't have express.bodyParser(). but I do have express.json() and express.cookieParser(). and express.methodOverride(). How do I know which one of these is causing the issue?

Comment: Middleware in express (in general) is anything called with `app.use()`. All middleware of the `express` object needs to be replaced. From the guild I linked to, `express.json()`, `express.bodyParser()`, and `express.urlencoded()` all should be replaced with `bodyParser()`, which is exactly what you need. I've edited my post to be more specific on what you should replace.

Comment: now when I start it I get this warning: body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares app.js:37:9
I thought body-parser was the new one?

Comment: I guess its actually an error. my app logs give me Process exited with status 1. body-parser depreciated bodyParser: user individual json/urlencoded middlewares at app.js:37:9. I thought the whole point was that now everything is included in app.use(bodyParser())? I put my updated server code in my question so that you can verify that I am doing things like you have explained in your answer